# Escaping Form Data

Tags: php, security, escaping

I'm having a bit of a problem with escaping data, or at least, the cleanliness of the code involved with it.

Let's say, I'm escaping a textfield named "FirstName" and it looks something like this:

```
$FirstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['FirstName']);
$FirstName = preg_replace( "/[<>#$%]/", "", $FirstName);
$FirstName = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $FirstName);
```

Is there anyway I can just put the last 2 lines in some sort of loop, let's say like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $value)
{
    $value = preg_replace( "/[<>#$%]/", "", $value);
    $value = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $value);
}
```

where then all I have to do later is

```
$FirstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['FirstName']);
```

where $_POST['FirstName'] has already been stripped of the other characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Make the `foreach` loop by-reference instead of by-value like so:

```
foreach($_POST as $name => &$value)
{
    $value = preg_replace( "/[<>#$%]/", "", $value);
    $value = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $value);
}
```

Note the ampersand in front of the `$value`. That means the `$value` you get as you iterate over the array is a *reference* to the value in the array itself rather than a copy of that value.

Comment: Actually, after a day of testing this, it seems to have a problem.

Let's say I have 3 POSTS being submitted. Name, email, then phonenumber. Your solution gives the last of the POSTs submitted the value of the second last POST. In this case, it gives phonenumber the value of email. Any thoughts?